# The type or namespace does not exists in the namespace .Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have all of a sudden stumpled upon a weird error in my .Net Core MVC project. It tells me that: *The type or namespace name 'Tripmetadata' does not exists in the namespace 'MSPFrontend.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have plenty views that are utilizing models from this folder without any trouble. In my `_ViewImports.cshtml` I have:

```
@using MSPFrontend.Models
```

## Tripmetadata.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MSPFrontend.Models
{
    public partial class Tripmetadata
    {
        public Tripmetadata()
        {
            Tripgpsdata = new HashSet<Tripgpsdata>();
            Tripstate = new HashSet<Tripstate>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Tripid { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Start Timestamp")]
        public long? Starttimestamp { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "End Timestamp")]
        public long? Endtimestamp { get; set; }

        public long? Duration { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Average Speed")]
        public decimal? AvgSpeed { get; set; }

        public decimal? Distance { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Tripgpsdata> Tripgpsdata { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tripstate> Tripstate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the namespace of `Tripmetadata.cs`?

Comment: Are you sure the Class `Tripmetadata` is `Public`??

Comment: Can you Show the Code inside `Tripmetadata.cs`

Comment: I have added the code for tripmetadata.cs

Comment: It seems like Visual Studio for some weird reason fixed the error all by itself. It does not appear anymore.

Comment: Sometime Restating Visual Studio is the best way.. :D

Comment: Yeah. This is not the first time this has happened. I did however try to do all sorts of restarting of both VS and my PC. I even created a new project to just clear the "cache" if something was residing in there :P

Comment: I had this issue just today. It was related to an old VS 2015 .suo file. Deleted it and it went away.

Comment: I am using .NET core and Visual Studio 2017 and I just got this error and I have restarted the VS2017, deleted file and re-added it. But that didn't help. I deleted the .suo file also, but that didn't help either. Still getting the error. Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: Zeliax I had a similar problem and rebooting VS fixed it. Nasty.